# GC.AddMemoryPressure for unmanaged objects

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

What is the correct way to use Add/RemoveMemoryPressure for unmanaged objects? I have an unmanaged object- but it makes heavy use of, e.g., STL containers. Am I supposed to constantly update the managed GC with every change to the total size of the unmanaged object? Or just it's raw allocation size? And when do I call RemoveMemoryPressure? Finalizer? Dispose()?

Comment: How do you expect the Garbage Collector to collect unmanaged objects?

Comment: @dtb: [GC.AddMemoryPressure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure.aspx) tells the runtime that there is a managed object keeping x bytes of unmanaged memory allocated (e.g. by having a reference to a COM object). This might then encourage the garbage collector to look for dead objects and run their finalizer, freeing the unmanaged memory in the process.

Comment: @dtb: By collecting the managed object that owns it.

Comment: @Wim Coenen: But shouldn't managed objects keeping unmanaged memory allocated implement IDisposable so the user code can free the memory immediately instead of waiting for the GC to be encouraged enough to run the finalizer?

Comment: @dtb: That would seem preferable, yes. I don't like finalizers either.

Comment: @dtb: The GC still needs to know how much memory is being owned here, so that it knows when to collect and what collection type to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure.aspx) (and noted by @Wim Coenen):

> In the simplest usage pattern, a
>   managed object allocates unmanaged
>   memory in the constructor and releases
>   it in the Dispose or Finalize method.
>   **Call the AddMemoryPressure method
>   after allocating the unmanaged memory,
>   and call the RemoveMemoryPressure
>   method after releasing it.**
>
> In more complicated scenarios, where
>   the unmanaged memory allocation
>   changes substantially during the
>   lifetime of the managed object, **you
>   can call the AddMemoryPressure and
>   RemoveMemoryPressure methods to
>   communicate these incremental changes
>   to the runtime**.

So you have to decide how much effort to put into tracking these changes and how much benefit you will get.

Comment: Yes - I ended up altering the default allocator for the native objects to inform the master object of all allocations, then using a Dispose() object in managed code to automatically update the GC of changes in all managed methods.